# how to sum all values in column between two empty cells in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I am completely new to Excel VBA, so I appreciate any help.
I have the following code in Excel VBA which creates two separate tables in sheet **output** after filtering the data in sheet **data** with certain conditions.

```
 Dim i, LastRow
  LastRow = Sheets("data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Sheets("output").Range("A2:L500").ClearContents

  Sheets("output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "first table"

   For i = 2 To LastRow
       If Sheets("data").Cells(i, "G").Value > 0 And Sheets("data").Cells(i, "G").Value   <= 2 Then
       Sheets("data").Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i

Sheets("output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3) = "second table"

For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("data").Cells(i, "G").Value > 2 And Sheets("data").Cells(i, "G").Value <= 3 Then
    Sheets("data").Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

What I want it to do is give the sum of all values of some specific column (say, column C) for each table (separately for table 1 and separately for table 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work whether you have one space or fifty spaces between your tables:

```
Sub SumTablesByColumn(sCol As String)
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim lStartRow As Long

lStartRow = 1
counter = 1
lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(sCol & 500000).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To lLastRow + 1
    If Range(sCol & x).Value <> "" And Range(sCol & x + 1).Value <> "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
    ElseIf Range(sCol & x).Value <> "" And Range(sCol & x + 1).Value = "" Then
        Range(sCol & counter + 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & sCol & lStartRow & ":" & sCol & counter & ")"
        x = x + 1
        If Range(sCol & x + 1).Value <> "" Then
            lStartRow = x + 1
            counter = x + 1
        End If
    ElseIf Range(sCol & x).Value = "" And Range(sCol & x + 1).Value <> "" Then
        lStartRow = x + 1
        counter = x + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```